# How to send a tweet as the current logged-in user?

Tags: php, twitter

I have a very simple form, consisting of a textarea and a submit button.

Is it possible to send the text as a tweet when someone pushes the button, if the user is already logged into twitter on another tab ?

I want to try a very simple mockup for something, I just need to send a tweet, do I still need to mess with oAuth ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not possible. It would be quite a security issue if any website could just send tweets with your account without authorization.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of. Of course you can't, for security reasons ^^; Well users will have to authorize my website to send tweets then.

Answer (score 1):

You've to register an application with Twitter API, Then make Authentication for the user.
After that you can post tweets or whatever your permissions allow.

Posting tweets without Authentication is very dangerous and can be considered as malware.

You can use some ready-to-use libraries to help you with the oAuth, instead of re-inventing the wheel.